# Не работает Nivo Zoom

Tags: jquery

Просмотрел всё. Не знаю, где ошибка. Проверил все подключаемые файлы. Код плагина не менял
Коды: http://jsfiddle.net/UqGTJ/ Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем вы выложили на jsFiddle скрипт плагина? )) Вы собираетесь его использовать или переписать под себя? И там же нет самого главного - инициализации этого плагина. Когда видите перевод аналогичных мануалов на каком-то русскоязычном сайте, то ищите [официальный сайт данного плагина](http://nivozoom.dev7studios.com). Скачиваете свежую версию и читаете оригинальную инструкцию. Тогда работа его - гарантирована.

P.S. На jsFiddle, слева в меню, есть пункт "Add Resources", куда и надо подключать внешние библиотеки, css, etc. Тогда [будет работать и там](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/UqGTJ/7/). ))

Comment: не работало, потому что я подключал jquery.nivo.zoom.js, а не jquery.nivo.zoom.pack.js

Но почему? мне надо изменить исходник плагина

Comment: всё ок. работает. это я потёр случайно какие-то строки. Спасибо!

Comment: если вам дали правильный ответ, то выберите его и закройте вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Вам эти ошибки говорят о чём-нибудь?

[image]

Comment: у меня ошибок нет. разумеется, я включал firebug

Comment: @olegall возможно вы упустили тег base, но и по коду ясно, что в jsfiddle не будет это работать.

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть на глаз, что не так

Comment: Ну извините, это не 20 строчек нативного js, чтобы на глаз определить, что не работает. Нужна полная сборка.